# how to set buffer local variable in emacs

Tags: emacs

I'd like to set a buffer-local variable (specifically mark-ring) to the default value (nil). How can I do this task? Is the only option to create some function and bind it to a key sequence in init.el file?

Comment: `mark-ring` is automatically made buffer local as soon as you set it, and it's default value *is* `nil`.  `(setq mark-ring nil)` should do the trick.... I think I could use more details in what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: I have a buffer and I want to erase its mark ring history

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`M-x eval-expression (setq mark-ring nil)` (also `M-: (setq mark-ring nil)`)